# Group by a list of string with specific substring

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a list of emails and I want to group by `mylist` with domain names or specific substring that contains all of string items(eg: @gmail.com or @yahoo.com).

Please note that I don't want just gmail and yahoo because there are many domains like @yahoo.fr or @hotmail.com.

After that, I want to add all of subgroup items into own separated list string.

*e.g.*:

```
var Emails = new List<string> 
{
"a@gmail.com",
"b@yahoo.fr",
"c@tafmail.com",
"b@mail.ru"
};
```

I tried group by with regex parameter, but it didn't work

Comment: Are you saying you want to group by domain? Or what?

Comment: Yes, I want to group by domain

Comment: Please add the exact results you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this to get a Dictionary of domain to email addresses:

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<string>> emailsByDomain = emails
    .GroupBy(e => e.Split('@', 2)[1].ToLowerInvariant())
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Basically we split the email address at the "@", take the second half, convert it to lowercase, and then use that as the dictionary key.

If there's a possibility that some of your list might not be an email address (no @) then you can filter those out with a `.Where`:

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<string>> emailsByDomain = emails
    .Where(e => e.IndexOf('@', StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
    .GroupBy(e => e.Split('@', 2)[1].ToLowerInvariant())
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Note that depending on your version of .NET, you might need to change the `.GroupBy` line to this: `.GroupBy(e => e.Split(new string[] { "@" }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].ToLowerInvariant())`

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/RWRC92562)

Answer (score 1):

Fun one. @ProgrammingLlama has a good idea with the Dictionary.

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

List<string> emails = new()
{
    "a@gmail.com",
    "b@yahoo.fr",
    "c@yahoo.fr",
    "notanemail",
    "c@tafmail.com",
    "b@mail.ru"
};

var groupedEmails = from email in emails
                    where email.Contains("@")
                    let domain = email.Substring(email.IndexOf("@") + 1)
                    group email by domain into g
                    select new { Domain = g.Key, Emails = g };

var dictionaryEmails = groupedEmails.ToDictionary(x => x.Domain, x => x.Emails);

System.Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(dictionaryEmails, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true }));
```

Result

```
{
  "gmail.com": [
    "a@gmail.com"
  ],
  "yahoo.fr": [
    "b@yahoo.fr",
    "c@yahoo.fr"
  ],
  "tafmail.com": [
    "c@tafmail.com"
  ],
  "mail.ru": [
    "b@mail.ru"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try .ToLookup() and pass in either the regex or substring from the index of @